# How to add a dropdown

Tags: java, android

I get a nullpointerexception with this code. I'm trying to add a spinner / dropdown to the white area of my screen. The offending code is:

```
package dev.android.gamex;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CatchGame cg;
    public TextView textView;
    public LinearLayout mainLayout;
    private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;


    // add items into spinner dynamically
    public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

    }

    // start app
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout menuLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        menuLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String str = "Score: 0";
        textView.setText(str);
        menuLayout.addView(textView);

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Pause");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                togglePausePlay();
            }
        });
        menuLayout.addView(button);


//        addItemsOnSpinner2();

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("list 1");
        list.add("list 2");
        list.add("list 3");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        menuLayout.addView(spinner2);


        mainLayout.addView(menuLayout);

        cg = new CatchGame(this, 5, "Jamie", onScoreListener);
        cg.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_land_mdpi));
        mainLayout.addView(cg);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(mainLayout);
    }

    private void togglePausePlay() {
        if (cg.paused) {
            // play
            //  getSupportActionBar().hide();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // pause
            //    getSupportActionBar().show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        cg.paused = !cg.paused;
    }

    private OnScoreListener onScoreListener = new OnScoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScore(int score) {
            textView.setText("Score: " + score);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // method called when top right menu is tapped
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        int difficulty = cg.NBRSTEPS;
        String name = cg.heroName;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item11:
                cg = new CatchGame(this, 3, name, onScoreListener);
                setContentView(cg);
                mainLayout.addView(cg);
                getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                setContentView(mainLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.item12:
                cg = new CatchGame(this, 5, name, onScoreListener);
                setContentView(cg);
                mainLayout.addView(cg);
                getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                setContentView(mainLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.item13:
                cg = new CatchGame(this, 7, name, onScoreListener);
                setContentView(cg);
                mainLayout.addView(cg);
                getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                setContentView(mainLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.item14:
                cg = new CatchGame(this, 9, name, onScoreListener);
                setContentView(cg);
                mainLayout.addView(cg);
                getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                setContentView(mainLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.item15:
                cg = new CatchGame(this, 11, name, onScoreListener);
                setContentView(cg);
                mainLayout.addView(cg);
                getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                setContentView(mainLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.item21:
                cg = new CatchGame(this, difficulty, "Jamie", onScoreListener);
                setContentView(cg);
                mainLayout.addView(cg);
                getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                setContentView(mainLayout);
                return true;
            case R.id.item22:
                cg = new CatchGame(this, difficulty, "Spaceship", onScoreListener);
                setContentView(cg);
                //mainLayout.addView(cg);
                //getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                //setContentView(mainLayout);
                return true;
            default:
                cg.paused = true;
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}

interface OnScoreListener {
    void onScore(int score);
}

class CatchGame extends View {
    int NBRSTEPS; // number of discrete positions in the x-dimension; must be uneven
    String heroName;
    int screenW;
    int screenH;
    int[] x; // x-coordinates for falling objects
    int[] y; // y-coordinates for falling objects
    int[] hero_positions; // x-coordinates for hero
    Random random = new Random();
    int ballW; // width of each falling object
    int ballH; // height of ditto
    float dY; //vertical speed
    Bitmap falling, hero, jamie2, jamieleft, jamieright;
    int heroXCoord;
    int heroYCoord;
    int xsteps;
    int score;
    int offset;
    boolean gameOver; // default value is false
    boolean toastDisplayed;
    boolean paused = false;

    OnScoreListener onScoreListener;

    // constructor, load images and get sizes
    public CatchGame(Context context, int difficulty, String name, OnScoreListener onScoreListener) {
        super(context);
        NBRSTEPS = difficulty;
        heroName = name;
        this.onScoreListener = onScoreListener;

        x = new int[NBRSTEPS];
        y = new int[NBRSTEPS];
        hero_positions = new int[NBRSTEPS];
        int resourceIdFalling = 0;
        int resourceIdHero = 0;
        if (heroName.equals("Jamie")) {
            resourceIdFalling = R.mipmap.falling_object2;
            resourceIdHero = R.drawable.left_side_hdpi;
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.background));
        }
        if (heroName.equals("Spaceship")) {
            resourceIdFalling = R.mipmap.falling_object;
            resourceIdHero = R.mipmap.ufo;
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.space));
        }
        falling = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceIdFalling); //load a falling image
        hero = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceIdHero); //load a hero image
        jamieleft = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.left_side_hdpi); //load a hero image
        jamieright = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.right_side_hdpi); //load a hero image

        ballW = falling.getWidth();
        ballH = falling.getHeight();
    }

    public CatchGame(Context context, int difficulty, String name, OnScoreListener onScoreListener, Drawable background) {
        this(context, difficulty, name, onScoreListener);
        this.setBackground(background);
    }

    // set coordinates, etc.
    void initialize() {
        if (!gameOver) { // run only once, when the game is first started
            int maxOffset = (NBRSTEPS - 1) / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                int origin = (screenW / 2) + xsteps * (i - maxOffset);
                x[i] = origin - (ballW / 2);
                hero_positions[i] = origin - hero.getWidth();
            }
            int heroWidth = hero.getWidth();
            int heroHeight = hero.getHeight();

            hero = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(hero, heroWidth * 2, heroHeight * 2, true);
            hero = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(hero, heroWidth * 2, heroHeight * 2, true);
            jamieleft = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(jamieleft, jamieleft.getWidth()* 2, jamieright.getWidth() * 2, true);
            jamieright = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(jamieright, jamieright.getWidth()* 2, jamieright.getWidth() * 2, true);

            heroYCoord = screenH - 2 * heroHeight; // bottom of screen

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            y[i] = -random.nextInt(1000); // place items randomly in vertical direction
        }

        offset = (NBRSTEPS - 1) / 2; // place hero at centre of the screen
        heroXCoord = hero_positions[offset];

        // initialize or reset global attributes
        dY = 2.0f;
        score = 0;
        gameOver = false;
        toastDisplayed = false;
    }

    // method called when the screen opens
    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        screenW = w;
        screenH = h;
        xsteps = w / NBRSTEPS;
        initialize();
    }

    // method called when the "game over" toast has finished displaying
    void restart(Canvas canvas) {

        toastDisplayed = true;
        initialize();
        draw(canvas);
    }

    // update the canvas in order to display the game action
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (toastDisplayed) {
            restart(canvas);
            return;
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int heroHeight = hero.getHeight();
        int heroWidth = hero.getWidth();
        int heroCentre = heroXCoord + heroWidth / 2;

        Context context = this.getContext();

        // compute locations of falling objects
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            if (!paused) {
                y[i] += (int) dY;
            }
            // if falling object hits bottom of screen
            if (y[i] > (screenH - ballH) && !gameOver) {
                dY = 0;
                gameOver = true;
                paused = true;
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "GAME OVER!\nScore: " + score, duration);
                toast.show();
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toast.cancel();
                        toastDisplayed = true;
                    }
                }, 3000);
                //Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                // Vibrate for 3000 milliseconds
                //v.vibrate(3000);

            }
            // if the hero catches a falling object
            if (x[i] < heroCentre && x[i] + ballW > heroCentre &&
                    y[i] > screenH - ballH - heroHeight) {

                y[i] = -random.nextInt(1000); // reset to new vertical position
                score += 1;
                onScoreListener.onScore(score);
            }

        }

        canvas.save(); //Save the position of the canvas.

        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(falling, x[i], y[i], null); //Draw the falling on the canvas.
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(hero, heroXCoord, heroYCoord, null); //Draw the hero on the canvas.

        canvas.restore();
        //Call the next frame.
        invalidate();
    }

    // event listener for when the user touches the screen
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (paused) {
            paused = false;
        }
        int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
        if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || gameOver) { // non-touchdown event or gameover
            return true; // do nothing
        }
        int coordX = (int) event.getX();
        int xCentre = (screenW / 2) - (hero.getWidth() / 2);
        int maxOffset = hero_positions.length - 1; // can't move outside right edge of screen
        int minOffset = 0; // ditto left edge of screen

        if (coordX < xCentre && offset > minOffset) { // touch event left of the centre of screen
            offset--; // move hero to the left

            if(coordX < heroXCoord)// + heroWidth / 2)
                hero = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(jamieleft, jamieleft.getWidth() , jamieleft.getHeight() , true);

        }
        if (coordX > xCentre && offset < maxOffset) { // touch event right of the centre of screen
            offset++; // move hero to the right

            if(coordX > heroXCoord)
                hero  = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(jamieright, jamieright.getWidth() , jamieright.getHeight() , true);

        }
        heroXCoord = hero_positions[offset];

        return true;
    }
}
```

The trace:

```
 main
                  Process: dev.game.adventure, PID: 5294
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dev.game.adventure/dev.android.gamex.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                      at dev.android.gamex.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The repository is [available online.](http://github.com/montao/gamex)

My XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My layout is supposed to look like this. The dropdown is supposed to appear to the right of the pause button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `findViewById` after calling `setContentView` .

And remove other `setContentView(mainLayout);` in your code .

Try

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // you should call findViewById after calling setContentView
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ...
}
```

**Edit**

You can try like this

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout menuLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
menuLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
Button button = new Button(this);
Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

menuLayout.addView(textView);
menuLayout.addView(button);
menuLayout.addView(spinner2);

mainLayout.addView(menuLayout);
```

**Edit**
`activity_main`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="score"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="pause"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>
</LinearLayout>

<your_package.CatchGame
    android:id="@+id/catch_game"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Add `CatchGame` as a class .

`MainActivity`

```
private CatchGame mCatchGame;
private TextView mTextView;
private Button mButton;
private Spinner mSpinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCatchGame = (CatchGame) findViewById(R.id.catch_game);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_score);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
    mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // do something here you want
}
```

Comment: try again .I edited .

Comment: Now I get NPE at this `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

Comment: Could you edit the code you modified?

Comment: I think it is because I didn't use any XML and now I'm forced to use XML for no good reason. Everybody hates XML.

Comment: Yes, you should use xml code .And when you create activity .It will create xml code .Won't you ?

Comment: You should create in `res/layout` folder .

Comment: You can look [android_acitivities](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_acitivities.htm)

Comment: Totally absurd that I must rewrite the entire application just to add a dropdown. I hate XML

Comment: You can create a xml code ,And add `Spinner` in it .It is ok .

Comment: Ok. So I'm starting over the entire project just to add a dropdown. I can't believe it.

Comment: NoNoNo,You just create xml code ,And add like this `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` .

Comment: And if you create `Activity` .You can see the xml code of it .Did you have it ?

Comment: It doesn't work. I must rewrite my entire app. It didn't use XML and now I must use XML for everything.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent`

Comment: Could you show the detail log ?

Comment: I'm trying to do something trivial: Add a dropdown. Now I'm forced to rewrite the entire app. I hate Android.

Comment: I edited it for you .Wait for moment .Enjoy it.

Comment: Excellent! It works!!!

Comment: Good luck to you.